# Why is "import" underlined in red in VSCode?

Tags: python, pandas, command-line

I would like to run a couple of basic scripts from a file called **import_process_eda.py**.

However, `import` is underlined in red when applied to the 4 dictionaries - i.e. pandas, numpy, matplotlib and seaborn - that I would like to use throughout the script.

Each time I run `python3 import_process_eda.py`, I receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`.

I've run the code from Anaconda prompt under the **"base"** virtual environment, which has pandas installed.

Comment: Make sure that you're actually in the Anaconda environment in VSCode. There are instructions to activate the Anaconda environment [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) - make sure you've followed those.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the libraries you need locally before being able to import them into a project.
You can do this in different ways:

1. Through the terminal using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) (ie: pip install pandas),
2. Importing them directly from the [VSCode Extension Library](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery),
3. Using the [anaconda environment](https://www.anaconda.com).